# How to append textbox value to the nearest span?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery datatables and want to apply calculation on it, it is hard to do so i want to append value of textbox to invisible span. How can i do this? with this following code it is only working on 1 textbox of same id i want to apply on all textbox of same id.

```js
$('td').each(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
    var txtvalue = $('#curr_sales').val();
    $("#curr").closest('span').text(txtvalue);
    console.log(txtvalue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="number" id="curr_sales" size="5" name="curr_sales" placeholder="Current Sales" required><span id="curr"></span></td>
<td><input type="number" id="curr_sales" size="5" name="curr_sales" placeholder="Current Sales" required><span id="curr"></span></td>
<td><input type="number" id="curr_sales" size="5" name="curr_sales" placeholder="Current Sales" required><span id="curr"></span></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: id is unique you cant give all elements the same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ids have to be unique**, they cannot recycle an already existing Id. Use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead

Also, to output the result to the closest `<span>` go up to the parent and find the `<span>` child from the `<tr>`.

Also, you can bind more than one event to the `<input>` if needed by using the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

---

### Output

[image: Sample output]

---

### Code Snippet

```js
$('td').each(function() {
  $("input").on("keyup blur", function() {
    var txtvalue = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find('span').text(txtvalue);
    console.log(txtvalue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="curr_sales" size="5" name="curr_sales" placeholder="Current Sales" required><span class="curr"></span></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="curr_sales" size="5" name="curr_sales" placeholder="Current Sales" required><span class="curr"></span></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="curr_sales" size="5" name="curr_sales" placeholder="Current Sales" required><span class="curr"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you read [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

I would completely rewrite (example below).  Targeting Ids is problematic because you can only have a single html element with and id, which makes jQuery non-reusable.  Targeting `span` also makes the jQuery code fragile, because someone else comes along and changes the span to a div and jQuery stops working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-populate-target").on('keyup change', function() {
    var txtvalue = $(this).val();
    var selector = $(this).data('populate-target');
    $(this).closest('.js-populate-container').find(selector).text(txtvalue);
    console.log(txtvalue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="js-populate-container">
        <input type="number" size="5" name="curr_sales" placeholder="Current Sales" required class="curr_sales js-populate-target" data-populate-target=".js-populator">
        <span class="js-populator"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="js-populate-container">
        <input type="number" size="5" name="curr_sales" placeholder="Current Sales" required class="curr_sales js-populate-target" data-populate-target=".js-populator">
        <span class="js-populator"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="js-populate-container">
        <input type="number" size="5" name="curr_sales" placeholder="Current Sales" required class="curr_sales js-populate-target"  data-populate-target=".js-blah">
        <span class="js-blah"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

By putting the target in a data field, you can now specific specifically which elements get targeted per item.